# SQL query to Rails query (Case Statement)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  CASE responsible WHEN 1 THEN "true" ELSE "false" END AS responsible
FROM user_departments
```

How do I write this in rails? I tried a query as below:

```
Department.first.users.joins(:user_departments).select("users.*, CASE WHEN user_departments.responsible = 1 THEN true ELSE false END AS responsible")
```

but it does not work. How do I correct this query?

Comment: What is the error message?  Can you include the entire relevant code in your question?

Comment: (SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: true: SELECT  users.*, CASE WHEN user_departments.responsible = 1 THEN true ELSE false END AS responsible FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_departments" "user_departments_users" ON "user_departments_users"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "user_departments" ON "users"."id" = "user_departments"."user_id" WHERE "users"."enabled" = ? AND "user_departments"."department_id" = ? LIMIT ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Ruby or your SQL framework very well, but I can see that the query you are running from your Ruby code does not match the literal query which is working.  Try this version, which places `true` and `false` into single quotes.

```
Department.first.users.joins(:user_departments).select("users.*, CASE WHEN user_departments.responsible = 1 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS responsible")
```

If your SQL database does not have `true` or `false` keywords, then your current version might be interpreted as referring to a column called `true` or `false`.

For a brief SQL primer, string literals generally should be placed into *single* quotes, not double quotes.  Double quotes are for identifiers, such as things like column and table names.  And `true` or `false` by themselves as literals would only make sense if your SQL database supported them as keywords.

Comment: And Its running on rails console

Comment: Instead of string ' true ' I want Boolean true value then which changes are needed ?

Comment: You should tell us which database you are using, but really it would be better to open a new question as this one has already been answered.